# Scala: Is it possible to get partially applied function from leftfold?

Tags: scala, partialfunction, foldleft

I'm currently learning Scala, and I just wondered at fold-left.
Since fold-left is curried, you should be able to get a partially applied function(PAF) with a first parameter as below.

```
(0 /: List(1, 2, 3)) _
```

But actually, I've got an error.

```
<console>:8: error: missing arguments for method /: in trait TraversableOnce;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

Then I tried same thing by fold-right such as below

```
(List(1, 2, 3) :\ 0) _
```

In this way, it went correctly, and I could get a PAF such as *((Int, Int) => Int) => Int*

I know I can get a PAF by using foldLeft method, but I wonder whether it is possible to express it with '/:' or not.

Comment: Possibly due to the association of the operator, since it involves a colon on the right hand side. Try moving the underscore to the left side.

Comment: You could also just use foldLeft.

Comment: The use of the /: and :\ should be avoided in preference to the more explicit foldLeft and foldRight. You may want to read this official style guide: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore syntax does not work well with right-associative methods that take multiple parameter lists.  Here are the options I see:

1. Declare a variable type:

   ```
   val x: ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int =  0 /: List(1, 2, 3)
   ```
2. Similarly, use type ascription:

   ```
   val x = (0 /: List(1,2,3)) : ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int
   ```
3. Use the postfix notation:

   ```
   val x = List(1,2,3)./:(0) _
   ```
4. Use the `foldLeft` synonym:

   ```
   val x = List(1,2,3).foldLeft(0) _
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I played around with it, and couldn't find a configuration that works.

There's always the more explicit:

```
val f = List(1,2,3,4,5).foldLeft(0)_
```

Which is arguably neater. I'll keep poking around though.

Edit:

There's this:

```
val f2 = (0 /: List(1,2,3,4,5))(_: (Int,Int) => Int)
val x = f2(_+_)
```

But that's getting pretty ugly. Without the type annotation, it complains. That's the best I could do though.